# Convert SQL query to MDX?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Please help me how to convert below sql query into MDX

```
DECLARE @a varchar(10)
DECLARE @b varchar(10)
Set @a = 'welcome'

If @a='welcome'
set @b= 'raj'+','+'venkat'



print @b
```

I am very new in MDX so please help and give me some more to idea to learn MDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with member [Measures].[a] as "welcome"
member [Measures].[b] as iif([Measures].[a] = "welcome", "raj"+","+ "venkat", null)

select [Measures].[b] on 0 from [mycube]
```